# Compile pug template in Scala

Tags: java, scala, pug, scalatra, pugjs

I am using Scalate in my project.
I am trying to compile a simple pug template:

```
html
  head
    title Hello
  body
    h1 Header
```

Scala Code:

```
val engine = new TemplateEngine
engine.layout("temp.pug")
```

And I get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateException: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoad(TemplateEngine.scala:782)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoadEntry(TemplateEngine.scala:745)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.liftedTree1$1(TemplateEngine.scala:446)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.load(TemplateEngine.scala:440)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.load(TemplateEngine.scala:495)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.layout(TemplateEngine.scala:593)
```

So is it me or the library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops